# android: how to set listener for Viewgroup and its child views at the same time?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm using a customized adapter for my listview. Here is the code:

```
    public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Content>{

    private ArrayList<Content> items;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Content> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.items=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v=convertView;
        if (v==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_layout, null);
        }
        Content content=items.get(position);
        if (content!=null){
            TextView nm=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
            TextView sm=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.itemsubname);
            nm.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            nm.setText(content.getName());
            sm.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            sm.setText(content.getSubname());
        }
        return v;
    }
```

R.layout.list_items_layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<TextView android:id="@+id/itemname"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/itemsubname"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

When I used setOnItemClick(listener) to create the listener for my listview, although the listener was set,it can only recognize when I click the blank part of the viewgroup. If I click on any of the two TextView, it just can't respond.

Is there any ways to set a OnItemClickListener that can monitorthe viewgroup and its child views at the same time?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I don´t understand your question if you want to it do it in a normal way just remvoe this android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: If I remove android:descendantFocusability the listener will completely stop responding...

Comment: You can set a `onClickListener()` in `getView()` method in your adapter, on the textviews you want to be clickable.